# Microsoft Dynamics - Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I'm trying to create a new "incident" (case) in by Dynamics 365 instance via the Web API.

In my http request, I don't know which field are mandatory. I tried to only add the title, subject, and customer, but I have a Http 400 error back...

I'm using Postman do try my Http Request. If I send the following json

```
{
    "title": "Case created from Web api",
    "_customerid_value": "bb2b6a80-7102-e711-8101-3993bb354ff0"
}
```

But I had the error: *"CRM do not support direct update of Entity Reference properties, Use Navigation properties instead."*

So I tried to user the @data.bind trick (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx#Anchor_3)

```
{
    "title": "Case created from Web api",
    "customerid@odata.bind": "/contacts(bb2b6a80-7102-e711-8101-3993bb354ff0)"
}
```

I get the following error: *"An undeclared property 'customerid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values."*

So now I don't really now how to do it. Can we create a incident (in my case a "service Case") through the Web API ?

Thank you

Comment: Please let me know which browser you are using, try with micorsoft edge

Comment: The definition for error code 400 Bad Request is: _The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax._ 
It does not seem that your issue has to do with mandatory fields: Can you add your request to the question?

Comment: Without the code it's hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: Please paste the code you are trying.. or try using "Postman" to evaluate your Web API request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Just need to add *"_contact"* to the @odata instance.

```
{
    "title": "Case created from Web api",
    "customerid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(bb2b6a80-7102-e711-8101-3993bb354ff0)"
}
```