# Resolve error on deep insert of navigation property Dynamics WebAPI

Tags: json, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am using the [Microsoft Dynamics Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607689.aspx) to write data to an entity in Microsoft Dynamics 365. When I try to do a [deep insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx#Create%20related%20entities%20in%20one%20operation) I am receiving the error

> An undeclared property 'ccseq_employeeid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.

Why am I receiving this error and how can I resolve the error?

### JSON

```
{
    "ccseq_importdate" : "2017-05-28T04:00:00Z", 
    "ccseq_month" : "1", 
    "ccseq_year" : "2017", 
    "ccseq_name" : "Test", 
    "ccseq_status" : "100000000", "ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID" : 
    [ 
        { 
          "ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(6d2fd71b-32d1-dd11-a4f5-001a6449bbe7)", 
          "ccseq_clientid@odata.bind": "/ccseq_clients(663ebd00-73b9-4faf-90ed-f56bb9c2dc9b)", 
          "ccseq_navemployeeid" : "11111", 
          "ccseq_employeefirstname" : "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

`ExpenseTransactionSet` is the parent of `ExpenseTransaction` meaning that `ExpenseTransaction` has a lookup to `ExpenseTransactionSet`.  `ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID` is one to many relationship. `systemuser` and `ccseq_clients` are separate entities that are lookups in `ExpenseTransaction`.

I've also tried the below variations on the `"ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind"`

- `objectid_systemuser@odata.bind`
- `objectid_ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind`
- `ccseq_employeeid@data.bind`
- `ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind : systemusers()`
- `ccseq_employeeid_systemusers@odata.bind`
- `systemuserid_systemusers@odata.bind`

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761311/create-annotation-to-a-contact-entity-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-by-api) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631164/microsoft-dynamics-web-api) question and tried the suggested resolutions without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer reading [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/203648) thread.  The correct syntax for a Navigation Property in a deep insert is to use the Child Entity Name followed by brackets with the field name.  The json needs to be changed to the below

```
{
    "ccseq_importdate" : "2017-05-28T04:00:00Z", 
    "ccseq_month" : "1", 
    "ccseq_year" : "2017", 
    "ccseq_name" : "Test", 
    "ccseq_status" : "100000000",
    "ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID" : 
    [ 
        {
          // Next two lines are changed 
          "ExpenseTransaction[ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind]": "/systemusers(6d2fd71b-32d1-dd11-a4f5-001a6449bbe7)", 
          "ExpenseTransaction[ccseq_clientid@odata.bind]": "/ccseq_clients(663ebd00-73b9-4faf-90ed-f56bb9c2dc9b)", 
          "ccseq_navemployeeid" : "11111", 
          "ccseq_employeefirstname" : "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the metadata document `{org-url}/api/data/v8.0/$metadata`, can you check the element-type of the collection-valued navigation property `ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID`?

Is it the same type which has `ccseq_employeeid` as its navigation property? If not, and the property `ccseq_employeeid` belongs to the derived type, you may need to annotate the navigation property object as below:

```
{
    "ccseq_importdate" : "2017-05-28T04:00:00Z", 
    "ccseq_month" : "1", 
    "ccseq_year" : "2017", 
    "ccseq_name" : "Test", 
    "ccseq_status" : "100000000",
    "ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID" : 
    [ 
        {
          "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ccseq_navemployee",
          "ccseq_employeeid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(6d2fd71b-32d1-dd11-a4f5-001a6449bbe7)", 
          "ccseq_clientid@odata.bind": "/ccseq_clients(663ebd00-73b9-4faf-90ed-f56bb9c2dc9b)", 
          "ccseq_navemployeeid" : "11111", 
          "ccseq_employeefirstname" : "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here.  `ccseq_ccseq_expensetransactionset_ccseq_expensetransaction_ExpenseTransactionSetID` has an odata type of `#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata`. `ExpenseTransactionSet` is the parent of `ExpenseTransaction` which has lookups to separate entities of `systemuser` and `ccseq_clients`

Comment: Can you try adding `"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ExpenseTransaction",` as first property in the `ExpenseTransaction` elements being inserted. From your comment, it seems that OData layer expects the deep-inserted elements to be of type `ExpenseTransactionSet` and does not expect them to contain property `ccseq_employeeid`. You can search for `@odata.type` in http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html.

Comment: I received the error `A type named 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ExpenseTransaction' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.`